# Finding coordinates with functions that have high powers

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule, tangent-line

Am trying to find the coordinates of the points where the tangent is horizontal
on this equation:             
y = 4 + (x-5)^6

I have worked it to this point with the chain rule

y'=6(x-5)^5
however am unable to find the x coordinates.
Any help appreciated thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

we have $$y'=6(x-5)^5=0$$ if $$x=5$$ to find the find the Point  we get $$f(5)=4$$

Comment: Ah okay, so even if there's a large power the null point law still only applies once sorry just get confused with this.